# Format ISO_INSTANT to ISO_LOCAL_DATE

Tags: java, android

I need to format ISO_INSTANT date: 2019-10-31T06:55:04.578Z to ISO_LOCAL_DATE 31.10.2019. And then compare with today's date to change date format to the for example "Today 10:00" and "Yesterday 13:00''. The second one is simple, but how to format ISO_INSTANT?

Comment: If you're asking how to *parse* the [`ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) date string, did you try [`Instant.parse(text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Comment: *FYI:* The [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) format is `2019-10-31`, not `31.10.2019`. Did you mean that you wanted to *format* a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) with format `dd.MM.uuuu`?

Comment: If you don't have the `Instant` and `LocalDate` classes at your API level, did you look at the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#threeten-android-backport) library?

Comment: @Andres Yes. Sorry for the late answer - very busy day.